# how to generate equal number of two values in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, if-statement

I need to generate a series of "a" and "-a" randomly in bash. I have to have equal number of "a" and "-a" meaning that the total sum of the array should be zero. Something similar to this:

```
n=20;
for i in seq 1 1 n
do
    if test $RANDOM -ge 16378
    then
        a=1
    else
        a=-1
    fi
done
```

Some thing similar to this, will generate "a" and "-a" in a random way but the sum will not always be zero. How should I apply this condition in the code?!

Thanx

Comment: It's not really random if it's predictable.

Comment: Your condition wouldn't make it random anymore.

Comment: Are you trying to say that for _n_ number of `a`, there should be _n_ number of `-a`, so the sum is zero, but they should be ordered 'randomly'?

Comment: Just because the sample space is structured (in this case, sequences of values with zero sum) doesn't mean you can't choose an element from the space at random.

Comment: the randomness is just in  the order of the numbers like: [a a -a a -a -a -a a a -a ...]. @Jens

Comment: @WilliamLee yes, that's what I want but with "n/2" of "a" and "n/2" of "-a" ordered randomly. do you have a simple solution?

Comment: @Elin What is $RANDOM for? Is it for the length of the result, or deciding between 'a' or '-a'?

Comment: This is also tagged arrays, but there is no array.  That's confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm adding a separate answer since you may actually be looking for something much simpler. If you want to loop through 20 values, ten of which are `1` and ten of which are `-1`, in random order, I would just do this:

```
$ for i in {1..10}; do echo 1; echo -1; done | shuf
-1
1
-1
1
-1
1
-1
1
1
1
-1
1
-1
-1
-1
-1
1
1
1
-1
```

Comment: I like this answer.  Simply, and seems to meet the requirements.

Comment: it does indeed. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'll interpret your question as equivalent to creating an array of known length with some number of `a` and the same number of `-a`, then getting a random permutation of that array.

Do you need to do it in `bash`? If so, you can create an array of the desired length first, then shuffle it.

From the [**BashFaq**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/026):

> This function shuffles the elements of an array in-place using the Knuth-Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm.

```
#!/bin/bash

shuffle() {
   local i tmp size max rand

   # $RANDOM % (i+1) is biased because of the limited range of $RANDOM
   # Compensate by using a range which is a multiple of the array size.
   size=${#array[*]}
   max=$(( 32768 / size * size ))

   for ((i=size-1; i>0; i--)); do
      while (( (rand=$RANDOM) >= max )); do :; done
      rand=$(( rand % (i+1) ))
      tmp=${array[i]} array[i]=${array[rand]} array[rand]=$tmp
   done
}
```

*(copied from [Simple method to shuffle the elements of an array in BASH shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533569/simple-method-to-shuffle-the-elements-of-an-array-in-bash-shell))*

If you aren't limited to `bash`, you can just use [`shuf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/shuf.1.html) and a `for` loop to [do it as a one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36989910/1716866).

Comment: thanks for the answer, I have to use bash otherwise I could do this in python or matlab, I am not good in bash! I'll try this and let's see what I get! I'll be back if I have questions. :)

Comment: so what you are saying in the above code is that I have to generate the array first and then rearrange it. My question is more about how to generate that array with equal number of "a" and "-a" values. Let's say if the length of the array is n=20, I want 10 of them to be equal to "a" and the other 10 equal to "-a". But I also want them to be randomly distributed like [a a -a -a -a a -a a a -a ...]. I'm not sure If I am clear enough?! :/

Comment: What's wrong with generating them in a known order first, then shuffling them. Isn't that the same result?

Comment: It should be the same. The thing is that I am using this as a part of a larger code within another "for" loop. So it's just easier if I do every thing at once otherwise this will work also! Maybe I am just being lazy!!!! :p Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you have a particular algorithm you want to use, we might be able to help you implement it. If the one I suggested isn't good for your problem, then your question might be more about algorithms than about bash. So let me ask you this: **If you *could* do it in Python or MATLAB, what algorithm would you use there?** Anything you can do there you can translate back into bash. It may be the case that after you think about that question, you will find that you like the algorithm I suggested more.

Comment: I am now trying to use it. I suppose I do have to call this in my main code, yes?!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple, you just need to learn to use the RANDOM better.

To get a random in a range, then mod it by the length of the range.  In this case, it's binary, so $((RANDOM % 2))

```
declare -i total=0     # you need to define this as an integer for += later
for i in {1..20}; do
   declare -i num=$((RANDOM % 2))  # define an integer var
   [ $num -lt 1 ] && ((--num))     # if it's zero, change to -1
   echo $num      # see the number picked
   total+=$num
done
echo "total = $total"
```

I'm assuming you want to see the results.  If you want to sum it, then we'd declare a variable outside the loop, and use it.  I'll edit it in.

Comment: @SainHax Than you for the answer. This works similar to what I have which does not give a total of zero. Maybe I need to be more clear. in the above code, out of those "20" values I need 10 of them to be "1" and the other 10 be "-1".

Comment: @Elin yes, you weren't clear-- your last paragraph seemed to still be what you wanted.  I'll edit.

Answer (score -1):

This might be what you want. It produces a random number of 'a's and '-a's combined, half the number for each, make the number of 'a's in the string equal to number of '-a's in the string. Tell me if I have misinterpreted the question.
The maximum length of the string can be limited, tell me if this is required

```
# l represents half the length of the array
l=1; # Sets l to 1, set the following while statement evaluates true
# Sets l to $RANDOM until it is an even number 
while [ $((l % 2)) -ne 0 ]; do 
    l=$RANDOM; 
done;
echo $l;
# Sets m and n to l
n=$l; # n is the number of 'a's 
m=$l; # m is the number of '-a's
# Initialises result as an empty string
result="";
# Doesn't stop until both 'a's and '-a's have been exhausted, i.e. n and m both equal 0
while [ "$n" != "0" ] && [ "$m" != "0" ]; do
    # Decides between 'a' and '-a'
    i=$(($RANDOM % 2));
    # Evaluates true if $i is 0, and the number of '-a's has not been exhausted, however also evaluates true if the number of '-a's has been exhausted
    if ([ "$i" == "0" ] && [ "$n" != "0" ]) || [ "$m" == "0" ]; then
        # Appends 'a' to result
        result="$result a";
        # Decrement the amount of 'a's left
        n=$((n-1));
    # Evaluates true if $i is 1, and the number of 'a's has not been exhausted, however also evaluates true if the number of 'a's has been exhausted
    elif ([ "$i" == "1" ] && [ "$m" != "0" ]) || [ "$n" == "0" ]; then
        # Appends '-a' to result
        result="$result -a";
        # Decrements the amount of '-a's left
        m=$((m-1));
    fi; 
done;
# Prints the result
echo $result;
```

EDIT: Comments to the code have been added, as suggested by SaintHax

Comment: Why is l random, instead of a passed value?  Also, there are no comments in this code and you are using variable names l, n, m ?  This should be avoided.

It'd be a lot quicker, if you had a default action when m or n hit zero.

Comment: @SaintHax Sorry about the lack of clarity in my code, I will add comments as soon as possible, but bear in mind that I am a 15 year old with no formal training in programming. I'm just trying to help.