# avoid random array items in bash

Tags: bash, shell, random

I have the following code:

```
n=1

a_letters=("a" "b" "c" "d" "e")

while [ $n -le 3 ]; do
    uniqueLetters=($(printf '%s\n' "${a_letters[@]}"))
    rand=$[ ( $RANDOM % 5)] 
    echo "${uniqueLetters[$rand]}"
    n=$(( $n+1 ))
done
```

How can I avoid array items that was already printed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple method to shuffle the elements of an array in BASH shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533569/simple-method-to-shuffle-the-elements-of-an-array-in-bash-shell)

Comment: The `printf` is unnecessary; `uniqueLetters=( "${a_letters[@]}" )` would accomplish the same thing.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3846123/4957508

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do some bookkeeping:

2 possibilities:

1. Remove a used char from the a_letters array
2. Keep track of printed characters and run the random until you hit an unused one.

I would go for option 1:

```
n=1

a_letters=("a" "b" "c" "d" "e")

while [ $n -le 3 ]; do
    uniqueLetters=($(printf '%s\n' "${a_letters[@]}"))
    rand=$[ ( $RANDOM % ${#a_letters[@]})] 
    echo "${uniqueLetters[$rand]}"
    a_letters=( "${a_letters[@]/${uniqueLetters[$rand]}}" )
    n=$(( $n+1 ))
done
```

(untested).

What it does is remove the selected character from your array `a_letters` and use the array size in the random so that it automatically corrects for the reduced array size.

Comment: I thought about bookkeeping :-) What if I do want to keep the array elements in tact for future usage? Further more, the result should always be 3 letters. It needs to run once a day.

Comment: You could setup a copy array of `a_letters` every loop so that `a_letters` is unchanged (really the most straight forward option).