# How to get non repeating values displayed

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash

Q1=Hey
Q2=My
Q3=Name
Q4=Is
Q5=Bob

R=$[ ( $RANDOM % 5 )  + 1 ]
RQ1=Q${R}

echo ${!RQ1}

###############
R=$[ ( $RANDOM % 5 )  + 1 ]
RQ2=Q${R}

while [ "${!RQ2}" = "${!RQ1}" ]
do
    R=$[ ( $RANDOM % 5 )  + 1 ]
    RQ2=Q${R}
done

#up to here this never repeates
echo ${!RQ2}   

#################

R=$[ ( $RANDOM % 5 )  + 1 ]
RQ3=Q${R}

while [[ "${!RQ3}" = "${!RQ2}" && "${!RQ3}" = "${!RQ1}" ]]
do
    R=$[ ( $RANDOM % 5 )  + 1 ]
    RQ3=Q${R}
done

# here is where it "failes" if i run it 2x or more it will repeat RQ1 or RQ2
echo ${!RQ3} 

################

R=$[ ( $RANDOM % 5 )  + 1 ]
RQ4=Q${R}

while [[ "${!RQ3}" == "${!RQ2}" && "${!RQ3}" == "${!RQ1}" ]]
do 
    R=$[ ( $RANDOM % 5 )  + 1 ]
    RQ4=Q${R}
done

#This repeats and I do the same for RQ5 and so on and so forth
echo ${!RQ4}
```

Above is the script I have that I want to improve on. Essentially I have 5 variables Q1-5 with 5 different values. I use $RANDOM to pick a random number which in turn I stick to the end of Q and that comes up with a Q[1-5] out of random which I echo out and it displays. Great

Now the problem is that $RANDOM with 5 repeats .. i want 5 different outputs every time I run it. However I seem to hit a wall. I thought comparing variables as strings and if they match to redo the $random again would work but if i keep running the script it doesn't give me 5 different outputs. From my testing the first two echos work fine...haven't received a duplicate. However the 3rd+ echo going forward is up in the air as things start to repeat. Eventually I want to extend this to say Q[1-40] and have 40 different echos outputting different values.

Any ideas where I am going wrong? while loops worth it? if/then?

Comment: If you're trying to send this to 40 questions this is going to get very long very fast. The easiest solution is to shuffle 40 questions off the bat then the next question every time, rather than pick a random question and check it against all previous questions, as your current solution does. Your solution would imply that the 40th question would require checking it against all 39 other questions every time you generate a new random number, which is non-optimal. [Consider using an array](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-arrays).

Comment: after looking through the link provided .. you are correct about the array. I haven't learned that yet since I am starting out but below is what I used to fix this problem. I am copying this from another post I saw
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533569/simple-method-to-shuffle-the-elements-of-an-array-in-bash-shell

Comment: #!/bin/bash

shuffle() {
   local i tmp size max rand

   # $RANDOM % (i+1) is biased because of the limited range of $RANDOM
   # Compensate by using a range which is a multiple of the array size.
   size=${#array[*]}
   max=$(( 32768 / size * size ))

   for ((i=size-1; i>0; i--)); do
      while (( (rand=$RANDOM) >= max )); do :; done
      rand=$(( rand % (i+1) ))
      tmp=${array[i]} array[i]=${array[rand]} array[rand]=$tmp
   done
}

# Define the array named 'array'
array=( 'a;' 'b;' 'c;' 'd;' 'e;' 'f;' )

shuffle
printf "%s" "${array[@]}"