# choose x random (no repeats) file names from a directory of files and store them in a list?

Tags: bash

How would I choose x random file names from a directory of files and then store those names ina  list to use latter in the script?

I have a directory with a bunch of files in it... I would like when the script runs to read that directory and choose 3 of those file names and then assign them into a list... which latter in the script I can for loop over and do something with each entry.

Thanks

I'm a noob... please treat me as such.

(sudoCode example)

```
files = /path/*
random = 3 files names from the path, no repetitions

echo $random[0]
echo $random[1]
echo $random[2]
```

Comment: This might help: [Simple method to shuffle the elements of an array in BASH shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5533569/3776858)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can do it in three parts:

1. collect all filenames from path in temporary array;
2. loop once for each random filename desired, choose random element from temp array;
3. output selected filenames

In bash, that would look like:

```
#!/bin/bash

oifs="$IFS"                         ## save original Internal Field Separator
IFS=$'\n';                          ## set IFS to \n to accommodate spaces in filenames
a=($(find /path/to/files -type f))  ## temporary array holding all filenames
IFS="$oifs"                         ## restore original IFS
n=${#a[@]}                          ## number of files in array

for ((i=0; i<3; i++)); do           ## loop over number of random files desired
    b[$i]=${a[$((RANDOM % n))]}     ## choose random element from temp array
done

for ((i=0; i<3; i++)); do           ## loop again outputting chosen files
    echo "${b[i]}"
done
```

Now obviously for purpose of the example I have hardcoded `3` as the number of random filenames to choose, you can handle that any way you like, you should add a check that `((n > 0))` before using it with `$((RANDOM % n))`, and you can `unset` the temporary array if you like -- those are left to you.

If you have hundreds of thousands of files or millions of files, you way use a temp file instead of array and then use `sed` to pick a random line from the file.

Look things over and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: `RANDOM % n` has an uneven distribution when 65536 is not a multiple of n. To evenly distribute `RANDOM` regardless of divisor you compute the largest multiple of n that is less than 65536 for n=3: `n=3; m=$((n*65536/n))` gives `m=65535`. Then you rerun `while rnd=$RANDOM; do ((rnd<m)) && break; done` until it is.

Comment: Oh yes, `RANDOM` is far from perfect - with warts and all. For more than 16-bit values you can do some nutty stuff like concatenate two grabs, etc... Builtin `RANDOM` leaves much to be desired.

Comment: Given shell arithmetic does not respect division priority over multiplication: have to use `m=$((65536/n*n))` or `m=$((65536-65536%n))`

Comment: Yes, depending on the refinements to `RANDOM` the OP may need, the tweak to eliminate some of the inherent bias may be warranted. On the other hand, it if's just a pick-3 and the quality of the random number produced isn't paramount, then `RANDOM` will work. If the OP was concerned about that random quality, such as for cryptographic purposes, then shell wouldn't be the appropriate tool for the job.

Comment: `a=($(find /path/to/files -type f))` won't works as intended when pathnames contain blank characters.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin You will need to adjust the `IFS` if `-print0` is to be used in the array assignment. BTW, I think the algorithm has another problem: a file may be chosen more than once by the algorithm in the code, which will cause repeated filenames to be output.

Comment: That's what I did, I set `IFS` and restored it after filling the array.  Good catch, thank you.

Comment: wouldn't there be a chance to get the same filename twice with this?

Comment: Yes, technically you can loop collecting the random numbers in an array checking the previously stored numbers until you have unique randoms.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `shuf` util, it is a one-liner if there are only files (not subdirectories) in `/path/` :

```
shuf -e -n3 /path/*
```

You can store the random pathnames in an array (named `arr` below) like that:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d'' -r -a arr < <(shuf -e -n3 /path/*)
```

assuming pathnames don't contain a newline character. Or, as a slightly simpler alternative using `mapfile` (synonym of `readarray`):

```
mapfile -t arr < <(shuf -e -n3 /path/*)
```

If it is possible that pathnames contain newline characters, then:

```
mapfile -d '' arr < <(shuf -zen3 /path/*)
```

as remarked in the comments by [Léa Gris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7939871/l%c3%a9a-gris). This last version will work with any valid pathname and should be preferred if you are using   GNU utilities.

Comment: You don't really need IFS or the read builtin for this. Consider `file_array=( $(shuf -en3 *) )` to create your array, rather than parsing redirection from process substitution.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs That approach fails if the filenames contain blank characters.

Comment: Preferrably `null` delimited: `mapfile -d '' -t arr < <(shuf -zen3 /path/*)`

Comment: @LéaGris Yes, that will work even if the pathnames contain newline character. The `-t` option isn't needed in that case.