# How can I sort an array randomly in Fish Shell?

Tags: arrays, sorting, shuffle, fish

I have an array of strings, I want to shuffle the order of the strings.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533569/simple-method-to-shuffle-the-elements-of-an-array-in-bash-shell) but it deals with bash and I'm using fish shell. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `shuf` as with the Bash version, it's a lot cleaner in Fish:

Using `$PATH` as an example, since it's a preexisting array of strings:

```
shuf -e (string collect $PATH)
# or
set random_path (shuf -e (string collect $PATH))
```

The variable assignment assumes that there are no newlines in the existing array elements.